# Does the argmax of $x^{1/x} = e$, and why?

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

The function $x^{1/x}$ seems to be maximized when $x=e$.  I don't know how to take the derivative.  How do I prove this, if it's true?

Comment: you may want to write your function using $\exp$, i.e. $$x^{1/x}=\exp(\log(x^{1/x}))=\exp\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x}\right)$$ and then use chain / product rule to take the derivative.

Comment: An even better idea is to maximise $\ln x^{1/x}=(\ln x)/x$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log(y)=\frac{\log(x)}{x}$
differentiating, $\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1-\log(x)}{x^2}$
$\implies$ $y'=\frac{x^{\frac{1}{x}}(1-\log(x))}{x^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

As already said, logarithmic differentiation is the key
$$y=x^{\frac 1x}\implies \log(y)={\frac 1x}\log(x)\implies \frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1-\log(x)}{x^2}$$ So, there is an extremum for $\log(x)=1$ that is to say $x=e$.

But you need to prove that this is a maximum and, for that, you need the second derivative test
$$y'=y \left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)\implies y''=y'\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)+y\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)'$$ Since $y'$ is already $0$, at this point $(x=e)$ $$y''=y\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)'=x^{\frac 1x}\left(\frac{1-\log(x)}{x^2}\right)'=x^{\frac 1x}\left(\frac{2 \log (x)-3}{x^3}\right)$$ and for $x=e$ 
$$y''=-e^{\frac{1}{e}-3}$$ which is negative. So, $x=e$ corresponds to a maximum.